# (Javascript) Prime numbers in a given interval: for loop doesn't iterate

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, primes

In the code below is a prime test function (returns true if prime and false if not).
I am using it to print out prime numbers between 5 and 20.

The expected output is obviously 5,7,11,13,17,19

The for loop doesn't seem to iterate and just stays at 5.
The output is as if the script is stuck inside an infinite while loop.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, maybe the if statement isn't written correctly?
Still a bit new to javascript.

```
function is_prime(number){

    if (number==2 || number==3){
        return true;
    }
    
    if (number==0 || number==1 || number%2==0){
        return false;
    }

    if ((number+1)%6!=0 && (number-1)%6!=0){
        return false;
    }
    
    for(i=3; i-1<=parseInt(number)**.5; i+=2){

        if (number%i==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}


for(i=5;i<=20;i++){

    if(is_prime(i)){

        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Always debug your values: `console.log(i)` would've pointed you towards the underlaying issue.

Comment: That's the kind of issue you get when you do not declare your local variables. They become global.

Answer (score 3):

You've created a global variable named `i` in your `for()` loop - then you change that same variable in the function.

Use `let i` in **both cases**.

Answer (score 2):

You're not declaring your variable `i`, so JavaScript is creating it in the global scope. In your function you also haven't declared it so it's using the same variable, and the loops don't  execute as you expect.

Declare the variables with `let` so that they don't clash, as in

```
for (let i=5;...
```

See [Let on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `(let i = 5`  in the for loop you need to declare that i

```
for(let i=5;i<=20;i++){

    if(is_prime(i)){

        console.log(i)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you create a global variable in your loop. Declare the variable with let and everything will work fine.
P.S. use strict mode will not allow you to do some stupid mistakes again

Comment: this is the start of a really good answer, but please identify exactly what you mean in the code provided by the OP. For instance, you should mention _which_ variable has been made global and precisely how to code it correctly. The "strict mode" tip is a good one if worded a bit less "in your face" :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) in your `for` loop initializers, which is just good practice anyway, it's often well-advised to use different names for different variables, for a number of reasons:

- It makes your variable usage less ambiguous
- Helps prevent confusion later on (by both yourself and other readers of your code!)
- Makes debugging easier (If you're only using `i` in one place, then you know where to look if it you get an unexpected value in `i`)

As an example, if I'm nesting loops, or have multiple loops in a script, I'll often start with `i` and work my way down the alphabet, `j`, `k`, `l`, etc.

Essentially any pattern you use is fine, as long as it helps you keep track of your data!